# Jupyter notebook is not launching - AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.8

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\apu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2037, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1675, in init_webapp
    self.web_app = NotebookWebApplication(
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 183, in __init__
    settings = self.init_settings(
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 302, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1292, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "c:\users\apu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your IPython package is out of date as `time.clock()` was deprecated a couple of years ago and its use removed from IPython. Try upgrading your IPython: `pip install --upgrade ipython` and ensure you're running a version >= 7.1.0 (with 7.17.0 being most current).

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5651#issuecomment-669944295) to the GitHub issue from which this answer was copied and pasted here.